# After a DOM change, scroll back so that a reference element is positioned on screen at the same place it was before the DOM change took place

Tags: javascript, html

I have an application where the user moves stuff. After he or she does so,I want to reposition the screen to where it was before to reduce confusion. To do so, I want to automatically scroll so that a reference element is positionned at the same place on screen before the DOM moved.

I created a code pen to isolate and reproduce the problem of my app: https://codepen.io/VincentBlouin/pen/YzzMKxm

```
let centerTextDiv = document.getElementById('center-text');
let scrollDiv = document.getElementById('scrollable');

centerRect = centerTextDiv.getBoundingClientRect();

scrollDiv.scrollLeft = centerRect.x - (centerRect.width / 2);
scrollDiv.scrollTop = centerRect.y - (centerRect.height + 75);

let firstTextDiv = document.getElementById('first-div-text');

let firstText = firstTextDiv.textContent;
let firstChars = firstText.substr(0, 500);
let lastChars = firstText.substr(500, firstText.length);


let insertNewTextDiv = document.getElementById('insert-new-text');


setTimeout(()=>{
  firstTextDiv.innerHTML = firstChars;
  insertNewTextDiv.innerHTML = lastChars;
  //scroll here
}, 3000);
```

First the reference div is visible but after 3 seconds some text gets moved and the reference div is no more visible on screen.

In my real app the scrolling container is simply document.scrollingElement but I had to create a scrollable div in code pen. Also in my app x,y of getBoundingClientRect of my reference div is different before and after the DOM change.

Well, thank you. I thought this was going to be easy to solve but I feel confused.

Answer (score 1):

You need to recalculate the new scroll and apply it to `#scrollable` after the DOM changes:

```js
// Get centerRect coordinates again
centerRect = centerTextDiv.getBoundingClientRect();
centerRectMoveX = centerRect.x - (centerRect.width / 2);
centerRectMoveY = centerRect.y - (centerRect.height + 75);

// Apply to scrollDiv by adding it to the current value
scrollDiv.scrollLeft = scrollDiv.scrollLeft + centerRectMoveX;
scrollDiv.scrollTop = scrollDiv.scrollTop + centerRectMoveY;
```

This should be executed in the DOM chaging function:

```js
setTimeout(()=>{
  firstTextDiv.innerHTML = firstChars;
  insertNewTextDiv.innerHTML = lastChars;
  centerRect = centerTextDiv.getBoundingClientRect();
  centerRectMoveX = centerRect.x - (centerRect.width / 2);
  centerRectMoveY = centerRect.y - (centerRect.height + 75);
  scrollDiv.scrollLeft = scrollDiv.scrollLeft + centerRectMoveX;
  scrollDiv.scrollTop = scrollDiv.scrollTop + centerRectMoveY;
}, 3000);
```

Check it in this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/esm280rq/

Comment: In practice I don't know that the scroll position of #scrollable is "centerRect.x - (centerRect.width / 2)" and "centerRect.y - (centerRect.height + 75)" I hand coded this to illustrate the problem. The reference div,  can be anywhere within #scrollable. Also in the jsfiddle you shared, I don't see "text move in 3 seconds" positioned at the same place after the 3 seconds timeout.

Comment: I'm sorry but I think I shared a wrong version of the JSFiddle. This one is what I wanted to share: https://jsfiddle.net/3zy29hok/. Also, check this other for the version without hardcoded values: https://jsfiddle.net/3zy29hok/1/

Comment: Forgot to mention that in your real case, #scrollable will be the body element (document.body).

Comment: Thank you @belsierre but this always centers the reference element. What Im looking for is that even if the element was in a corner of the screen or even outside of the visible screen it scrolls back to a place where it seems like nothing moved. Like if the reference element was in a corner it would still be in that same corner after the DOM changed.

Answer (score 1):

**getBoundingRect** will change with the scroll so it's a bit hard to use it for these calculations. You can simply use **offset** of the elements to determine the scroll needed in relations to a div coordinates.

You can simplify by always scrolling to the **offsetLeft** and **offsetTop** of your element, it should always stay at the same position relative to the scroll element, even if the absolute offset changes.

Then if you want to center, you just need to adjust in function of the scroll element width and height and the element width and height. But these numbers won't change, the important part is to follow the *offsetLeft* and *offsetTop*, which are the number that actually move. Like this:

```js
let centerTextDiv = document.getElementById('center-text');
let scrollDiv = document.getElementById('scrollable');

// here are the formulas. This centers your div in the scrollable. 
// Normally using the same formula will always position the element at the same position relative to the scroll element.
// Here (scrollDiv.offsetWidth - centerTextDiv.offsetWidth) / 2 is to center, but only the offset left and top will change.
scrollDiv.scrollLeft = (centerTextDiv.offsetLeft) - ((scrollDiv.offsetWidth - centerTextDiv.offsetWidth) / 2);
scrollDiv.scrollTop = (centerTextDiv.offsetTop) - ((scrollDiv.offsetHeight - centerTextDiv.offsetHeight) / 2);
let firstTextDiv = document.getElementById('first-div-text');

let firstText = firstTextDiv.textContent;
let firstChars = firstText.substr(0, 500);
let lastChars = firstText.substr(500, firstText.length);


let insertNewTextDiv = document.getElementById('insert-new-text');


setTimeout(() => {
  firstTextDiv.innerHTML = firstChars;
  insertNewTextDiv.innerHTML = lastChars;
  scrollDiv.scrollLeft = (centerTextDiv.offsetLeft) - ((scrollDiv.offsetWidth - centerTextDiv.offsetWidth) / 2);
  scrollDiv.scrollTop = (centerTextDiv.offsetTop) - ((scrollDiv.offsetHeight - centerTextDiv.offsetHeight) / 2);

}, 3000);
```

```css
#scrollable {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

#main {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.flex-grow {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1 !important;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.side-div {
  width: 250px;
}

#scroll-reference {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;

}

#insert-new-text {
  max-width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div id="scrollable">
  <div id="main">
    <div class='flex-grow'>
      <div class='side-div' id='first-div-text'>
        left - At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="scroll-reference" class='flex-grow'>
      <div id="center-text">text move in 3 seconds</div>
    </div>
    <div class='flex-grow'>
      <div class='side-div'>
        At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat
        <div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='flex-grow'>
        <div id="insert-new-text"></div>
      </div>
      <div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Thank you, "offsetLeft" and "offsetTop" rather than "getBoundingRect" gave me a good tip. So I saved the left and top offset of centerTextDiv before the timeout and after the timeout, I added the delta offset (after minus before) to scrollLeft and scrollTop of #scrollable and it worked.